# Dateparse MON in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data source that returns a date as a string in the form of 'MON YYYY' (APR 2014, MAY 2014, etc.).

I tried making a calculated field off of this information with the following formula:

```
DATEPARSE('MMM YYYY', [Field1])
```

This is a sample set of the data I'm getting (I added the pipe as a divider):

> Field1  || Calculated Field
>
> APR 2014  ||  12/22/2013
>
> APR 2015  || 12/28/2014
>
> APR 2016  ||  12/27/2015
>
> AUG 2014  ||  12/22/2013
>
> AUG 2015  ||  12/28/2014
>
> AUG 2016  ||  12/27/2015

I've also tried to add a day field, but that results in the same incorrect data as above:

```
DATE(DATEPARSE('dd MMM YYYY','01 ' +[Field1]))
```

Is there something I'm perhaps misunderstanding about the dateparse function?

Comment: what database or file format are you using to contain the data?

Comment: Its an Oracle ODBC connection

Comment: I was using a tableau extract, not a live connection if that makes a difference

Comment: Just that some data sources don't support DateParse() but the ones you listed do, except perhaps ODBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `YYYY` means something totally different than `yyyy`.  The capitalized `MMM`was necessary for the MON type description. This worked for me:

```
DATE(DATEPARSE('MMM yyyy',[Field1]))
```

If you date the date off you'll get the hour, minute, second fields as well.

Dateparse converted it from a string [Field1] into a Date type using the aforementioned format of three digit month, a space, and a four digit year `(e.g. AUG 2014 -> 8/2/2014).`

Comment: please accept your answer if the question is no longer open

Comment: Says I have to wait two days :(